# Solving limit $\lim_{x\to 3}\frac{3^x-x^3}{x-3}$ without L'Hôpital's rule.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I have the following limit:
$$ \lim_{x\to 3}\frac{3^x-x^3}{x-3}$$
I solved it using the L'Hospital's rule, but I cannot solve it by converting to logarithm.
This is what I got so far:
$$ \lim_{x\to 3}\frac{3^{3\log_3x}(x-3\log_3x\ln3)}{x-3}$$

Comment: Hind: in denominator it should be 1 instead of $x-3$.

Comment: The duplicate target and more similar questions can be found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Clim_%7Bx%5Cto%203%7D%5Cfrac%7B3%5Ex-x%5E3%7D%7Bx-3%7D%24%2C%20AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Can you edit your question title? Because it is unclear what you want. You have written solve limit and then you write that you have already solved using L'Hôpital's rule. If you want it solved by a different method, please update the title so that it says clearly what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the derivative at $x=3$ of the function $f(x)=3^x-x^3$, id est $3^3\ln 3-3\cdot 3^2=27(\ln 3-1)$.